# Linker GCC Undefined reference to symbol

Tags: c++, linker, blas

I'm trying the following command:

```
gcc -o test test.o -lblas
```

which gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib64/libm.so.6 so try adding     it to the linker command line
```

/lib64/libm.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

However, when I add -lm at the end of the command, there is a whole bunch of error messages:

```
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,   
std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
[...]
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: When building C++ programs, use `g++` and not `gcc`.

Comment: Adding "-lstdc++" to the command line may help.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Joachim's comment applies even if he's linking. Manually adding libstdc++ isn't the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about that - ups.

Comment: This question can be closed.

Comment: @Mat Why? Sure, both `gcc` and `g++` invoke `cc1plus` and `ld` with slighlty different flags and options, but it can be easily overriden

Comment: @Joker_vD: it can easily be overriden if you know what you're doing. If you're struggling understanding what the above error means, you shouldn't even try and link manually.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you when I tried to link other libraries.

Here is my solutions:

1. install libtool;
2. add the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
3. I use root to make.

I don't know the exactly reason why it works on my Ubuntu. But I think you can try these steps.